# How to 'compare and find the best' best practice

Tags: ruby, algorithm

Let's say I have something like this:

```
def find_the_best(array)
  temp = 15435435435 # sufficiently large number
  value = 0
  array.each do |element|
    some_var = function_does_something_complex_and_returns_value(element)
    some_var < temp ? value = element[0]
  end
end
```

This sufficiently large number solution works, but it seems kinda hacky. What's the best way to handle this, particularly in ruby, but generally as well. The problem is that it really should be set to 0, then assigned the first value and then every value after that should be adopted only if it is smaller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't look like a sorting problem as much as best fit based on criteria.

You're looking for the smallest value, there is no need to have the temp value (unless there is something you aren't telling us).

Simply assume the first value will be the best and continue checking as you go.

```
best_value = array[0];
foreach( element in array )
{
    if( best_value > element )
        best_value = element;
}
```

Comment: you're right. Also, it's finding the best fit of a path, so if I get three nodes deep into a path and know it is a loosing path I can bail out on that path and go to the next one.

Comment: Using `foreach` in Ruby is highly unusual.

Comment: I think you're right. I've seen `for` used so infrequently I can't even remember the last time and forgot that `foreach` doesn't even exist in Ruby.

Comment: I don't think we should down vote him for using JS, as I specifically said any language would be acceptable.

Comment: My apologies - I was merely showing some pseudocode and focusing on the problem at hand than the language specifics to make sure @NoahClark understood the difference I was pointing out

Comment: Tagging the question as "ruby" usually indicates a strong preference. The way you asked for alternates was subtle enough I didn't notice. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is the `sort_by` routine to sort a list of objects by some arbitrary criteria:

```
best = array.sort_by do |element|
  function_does_something_complex_and_returns_value(element)
end.first
```

You may need to use `first` or `last` depending on if you want highest to lowest or lowest to highest.

Comment: How do we know that running a sort will be more efficient than a simple loop to find the smallest value?  Less code, but more execution in the background.

Answer (score 3):

```
array.min_by{|e| function_does_something_complex_and_returns_value(e) }
```

or

```
array.inject {|m,e| [m, function_does_something_complex_and_returns_value(e)].min }
```

Comment: Note that the `inject` version here is incorrect in that it returns the highest computed value, not the object that resulted in that computed value. Using `min_by` is a good idea.

Comment: Good catch. I think I can fix it by looking at the first item of the array. In general, I don't really like the inject version, it has inefficiencies.

Comment: There's nothing inherently inefficient about `inject` from a performance perspective, but it can be a lot more verbose to use correctly than a more specialized method.

Comment: Well, I was referring to my implementation using `inject`, not `inject` in general. The code block creates an array which means memory allocation, then it calls `min` which is a function call.  Both are useless overhead. Of course, for small arrays this is a moot point.

Comment: The overhead for small arrays is surprisingly minimal. Also note that `inject` without an argument simply uses the first element as the seed. Putting `array.first` in there is not only redundant, it's incorrect since you are testing element 0 to element 0 in the first iteration.

Comment: I didn't know that was the default behavior of inject. However, as far as correctness goes, you're mistaken: `min(a, a) = a`, so the iteration will take care of itself.

Comment: Although the result is correct, the use is incorrect. In this case the duplication is harmless but this may not be so in other applications where you introduce an "off by one" error by iterating over the first element twice.